# Chatbase API to get analytics data?

Tags: chatbase

We are using Chatbase for multiple clients that we identify with a different version number. 
See my previous question here: [Track multiple context for the same Bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211840/track-multiple-context-for-the-same-bot)

We have a dashboard for all those clients and would like to show them their own data. A bit like Google analytics allows it.

So:

1. Is an API in the pipeline (I couldn't find any existing resources)
2. If not, in what alternative way could we get the data to present it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [.csv export](https://chatbase.com/documentation/data-downloads) that is currently limited to the first 500 rows of your message variations report. It is on our roadmap to increase the scope of this report, however there is no official timeline for release.

Our recommendation for deploying an integration like you described in your message is as follows:

1. Have the user create a Chatbase account in order to obtain the API key
2. Have the user integrate their analytics on your platform by providing the API key
3. Send the messages from their bot to their Chatbase API
4. Provide the user deeplinks to the Chatbase reports from within your UI

Alternatively, you could configure your bot to send a redundant message to an internal database, or bigquery table to have access to all of your logs.

If you would like access to data you have sent to Chatbase up to this point, please contact chatbase-support@google.com and provide your bot's name and/or api key and we can provide a one-time export.